# onListItemClick didn't fired when implemented OnScrollListener (Android)

Tags: android

I implemented OnScrollListener to paging the listview!

The paging is ok! i scrolled the list and after i selected the item on listview onListItemClick didn't work!

Here is my onListItemClick and i extended ListActivity.

Comment: where have you declare onListItemClick() ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce your code to the relevant parts. Right now people will have a difficult time to find what makes you trouble. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just scanning through your code and I can't tell which class you're extending either ListActivity or ListFragment, so you can provide a more complete listing?

In the meantime, if you're extending ListView you should check out this article that shows how to set you onClick method:
[ListView with onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Otherwise, if you're extending ListFragment, then you can override this method to provide whatever behavior your looking for when a list item gets clicked:

`@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View clickedView, int position, long id)`

An example of what I'm talking about can be found here:
[ListFragment docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

Hope that gets you where you need to be.

David

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added onListItemClick().

Comment: If it solved your problem can you vote the solution up and mark it resolved? This will help other users

Comment: onListItemClick still doesn't fire! But thanks for your informations!